# Twitter Bootstrap mobile menu not working

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, joomla, joomla3.0

I have developed a website using Joomla3 and Twitter Bootstrap. In the mobile view and also in the tablet view main menu does not work. It does not open up or close up. I went through the console as well but no errors are shown.

*Given that I went thorugh all the existing question on the SO. None of them seems to help me.*

Link to the [web site]

How can I fix this?

## Update

Issue has been fixed. It's no longer existing in the site. Please see the accepted answer below.

Comment: It might be due to the fact that you have bootstrap.js being imported twice. Not sure if this causes conflicts but worth a try

Comment: Thanks if you can post this as an answer I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you inspect the site with the likes of Firebug or Chrome Dev Tools, you will notice that **bootstrap.min.js** is being loaded twice.

Loading multiple instances may cause conflicts and therefore might be the reason why your responsive menu isn't working. Try removing 1 instance of the `.js` file first.

Comment: How do Check if its loaded twice?

Comment: @GaneshSalunkhe - Open your browser inspector to view the source code.

Comment: **Elements** for Chrome, **Inspector** for Firefox and **HTML** for Firebug.

Comment: Sorry. But I am making mistake somewhere. I want to know which js is loaded twice?

Comment: If you're trying to detect duplicate instances of imported assets, please ask a new question. In **this** question, I simply used my browser inspector to check for multiple instances of any JS files

Answer (score 1):

This looks like, bootstrap 2.3, correct? As per the documentation:

http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html

```
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">

      <!-- .btn-navbar is used as the toggle for collapsed navbar content -->
      <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </a>

      <!-- Be sure to leave the brand out there if you want it shown -->
      <a class="brand" href="#">Project name</a>

      <!-- Everything you want hidden at 940px or less, place within here -->
      <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
      <!-- .nav, .navbar-search, .navbar-form, etc -->
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The differences I see between your code and the code from the documentation is that they use an anchor tag while you're using a button, and your classes are different. Try switching those up and see if it works!

Comment: Yes 2.3. I'll try and let you know.

Comment: I have updated the site as per the documentation. Still it does now work

Comment: Take a look a Lodder's comment above. Having two bootstrap.js files may be causing your collapse to run twice with only one click, consequently making the menu close immediately after opening it.

Comment: +1 for the all the help and reminding me to take a look at docs.